# How to add a message bar to custom canvas?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, pyqt

There is a simple code to add message bar to main window in QGIS:

```
iface.messageBar().pushMessage("Hello","World")
```

My question is how to add bar to my custom canvas `canvas = QgsMapCanvas()` in standalone application?
Is there possibility to display it on the bottom of canvas?

Comment: Perhaps this link might help: [Communicating with the user](http://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/communicating.html) where it mentions adding a message bar in your own custom dialog.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just a widget so you sure can. Normally you would add it to a layout however that will resize your canvas when it pops up which is a bit annoying IMO.  What you can do is just some logic to resize the bar to match the parent size when it is shown.

Here is some code that I use to do just that:

```
class MessageBar(QgsMessageBar):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MessageBar, self).__init__(parent)
        self.parent().installEventFilter(self)

    def showEvent(self, event):
        self.resize(QSize(self.parent().geometry().size().width(), self.height()))
        self.move(0, self.parent().geometry().size().height() - self.height())
        self.raise_()

    def eventFilter(self, object, event):
        if event.type() == QEvent.Resize:
            self.showEvent(None)

        return super(MessageBar, self).eventFilter(object, event)
```

Usage:

```
canvas = QgsMapCanvas()
messagebar = MessageBar(canvas)
messagebar.pushMessage("title", "message")
```